# Cause `ex` to automatically exit without saving if a pattern isn't found?

Tags: ex-mode, posix

I'm big on [scripted file edits using POSIX `ex`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269076/135943) rather than `sed -i` and co.  The big trick of course is how to ensure `ex` doesn't hang waiting for input if an error is encountered.

I just [wrote a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25057/how-to-perform-a-sed-in-place-substitution-that-only-creates-backups-of-files-th#comment468964_25057) about the possibility of using `ex` to edit a file conditionally, and only save a backup of the file if edits were made.

It seems that if there were some option which could be used to tell `ex` "In case of any error, `q!`" then this would be fairly simple conceptually:

```
ex -sc '%s/pattern/replace/g | !cp % %.bup' -cx file
```

Of course that copy command will fail on *any* special characters in the filename, but you get the concept; a better form would be:

```
ex -sc '/pattern/ | w %.bup' -c '%s//replace/g | x' file
```

Essentially what I'm asking for is a form of conditional logic in `ex` batch scripting, such that "If this pattern isn't found, `q!`; otherwise continue."

How can I do this with `ex`?

Comment: Interesting that the reverse case of automatically exiting if a pattern *is* found can be easily accomplished with e.g. `ex -sc 'g/exit_pattern/q!' -c '%s/change/stuff/g | x' file`, but this method doesn't adapt at all to my question as it actually operates line by line.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but you could make the substitution, check if the buffer is modified, if it is undo and make a backup, then redo the substitution. It would give something like: `vim -c '%s/pattern/replace/ge | exe &modified == 1 ? "undo | w %.bup | redo | write | exit" : "exit"' file`

Comment: It's fairly close, except for being not POSIX.  Would you mind [adding it as an answer?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3927/135943)  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since posting this question I've learned the trick of wrapping automated `ex` edits in pipelines, with `printf` used to send the actual commands.  This has the advantage that `ex` will not hang on error conditions.

The way I would do this now for a portable script would be:

1. Make a copy (backup) of the file.
2. Do the edits using `printf` to pipe commands to `ex`.
3. Delete the backup if it is identical to the edited file (i.e. no changes have been made).

Simplistically, this would look like:

```
cp file file.bak
printf '%s\n' '%s/pattern/replace/g' x | ex file
cmp -s file file.bak && rm file.bak
```

More robustly, I might do it like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -e file.bak ] && exit 1
[ -w file ] && [ -r file ] || exit 1
cp file file.bak
printf '%s\n' '%s/pattern/replace/g' x | ex file
cmp -s file file.bak && rm file.bak
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could make the substitution and check if the buffer is modified by looking at the value of the option `'modified'`.
If it is modified, undo, make a backup, redo and exit.
Otherwise, if the buffer is not modified, simply quit. It could give something like:

```
vim -c '%s/pattern/replace/ge | exe &mod ? "undo | w %.bup | redo | x" : "q"' file
```

But as you said in the comments, it's probably not POSIX.

Comment: I didn't realize that the `:w` command would be correctly terminated by a `|`—I was thinking of `sed`, wherein a `w` command can't be terminated by a `;` but only by a newline.  And this is still helpful even though not POSIX; thanks!

Comment: (Given that you use `vim` as the command rather than `ex` or `vi`, it's rather self-protecting against POSIX incompatibility.  If the user doesn't have `vim` but only some minimal POSIX implementation, the `vim` command won't even be found and they'll get an error at the shell level.)

Answer (score 2):

You could store whether to exit or not in a register, then execute it:

```
" store q! in register x
s/$/^Mq!/ | d x
"
" if pattern exists, store " in register x
g/pattern/ s/$/^M"/ | d x
"
" execute :q! if pattern wasn't found, :" if it was
@x
"
w %.bup
"
" ... more edits ...
"
wq
```

You probably don't want to use ex for any complicated control flow though. Maybe use a more fully featured programming language. Or in this case you could grep for the pattern first:

```
$ grep pattern file && ex -c 'commands' file
```